# Starting a detached screen session and a Java program with one command

Tags: linux, debian, gnu-screen

I found an answer on super user that the following should create a screen session in detached mode. But it is not working in my situation.

```
screen -dmS sessionname java -jar /root/programone/myprogram.jar
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using the `&&` operator. You can run a command based on a previous successful command. So `screen -dmS sessionname && java -jar /root/programone/myprogram.jar`, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

The Syntax is correct. But the screen sessions lives only if the program running in it lives.  So it's probably the Java program returned error or finished successfully, in other words, ended.

To test this feature of `screen`, you can do this:

```
screen -dmS cat cat
```

It will start a screen session named cat with the program `cat` running in it. then with `screen -ls` you can see the session named cat listed.  you can then use `screen -r cat` to attach it.